# hide html columns when exporting to excel

Tags: php, jquery, excel, header

I'm trying to export html table using header output in php. I'm using jquery to hide the columns by checkbox event.

My jquery code to unhide and hide column is:

```
$('.col').css('display','table-cell');
$('.col').css('display','none');
```

When I export my html table with hidden columns, the hidden columns still appears.
I want to hide those columns while exporting to excel using php header.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: This sounds like it's down to Excel's awesome* data transformation. You will most likely need to remove the column from HTML, export and then add the column back in again. *By awesome I mean useless.

Comment: Excel isn't a web browser, you shouldn't rely on CSS rules being applied or JavaScript being executed there.  Instead of "trying to export html table" to Excel, export the data itself in an Excel format as an entirely separate view of the data than your HTML-based view.

Comment: Rory: Removing the column works, but how do I add it back and on same index?

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for this, and I found

[How to remove style="display: none;" columns when exporting an HTML table to Excel? | The ASP.NET Forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1985239.aspx?How+to+remove+style+display+none+columns+when+exporting+an+HTML+table+to+Excel+); the trick is to clone your table first, then remove from it all elements with style "`display:none;`" before exporting:

> The easiest approach (if you can) might be to explicitly strip out any `<th>` and `<td>` elements that are not visible prior to submitting your form:
>
> ```
> // This will remove any hidden <th> or <td> elements from the DOM
> $("th:hidden,td:hidden").remove();
> ```
>
> [...] clone your existing html into a jQuery variable and then perform the remove from that actual variable:
>
> ```
> // When the stripped button is clicked, clone the existing source
> var $clonedTable = $("#my-table").clone();
> // Strip your empty characters from the cloned table (hidden didn't seem to work since the cloned table isn't visible)
> $clonedTable.find('[style*="display: none"]').remove();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("th:hidden,td:hidden").remove();
var $clonedTable = $("#my-table").clone();

$clonedTable.find('[style*="display: none"]').remove();
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided context for your answer and not just a snippet.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a small class class where you can generate xls sheets after populating arrays with the data you want in the sheet, its very easy to use, and can be expanded with your requirements, hope that helps: http://www.anchorx.com/ali/2011/02/27/create-spreadsheet-with-php/

Comment: Except that your class doesn't write valid .xls BIFF files; it writes csv files with an extension of .xls; and you don't even use PHP's built-in fputcsv() function to do it correctly